# Submitting form on pressing enter when focus is on TextArea?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, submit, form-submit

I have a form with a TextArea only. I want that when user presses <kbd>enter</kbd> it should submit the form but when user presses <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> it should go to new line in text area. It is a type of chat application. So either I do it with JavaScript or is there any way to do this in HTML or any other method I should use?

Comment: http://cburgmer.github.com/jquery-shiftenter/

Comment: thanks @SpYk3HH 
nice tutorial :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a `onkeydown` handler.  In the event handler, use a debugger to examinethe event passed to your handler.  You should be able determine when <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.  Use `evt.keyCode` and `evt.shiftKey`.